# DynamicLoaderComponent not recognized as type

Tags: angular, typescript

I am not able to inject the DynamicComponentLoader into a component's constructor.  I receive the error message below, at runtime.  The Angular type definition and the Angular implementation are v2.0.0-39.  And it's defined as an interface in the angular2.d.ts file.

**ERROR: Cannot resolve all parameters for MyAppComponent(?, ?). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.**

Here are the compilation settings:

```
tsc -w -m commonjs -t es5 --emitDecoratorMetadata -experimentalDecorators app.ts
```

What am I missing?

app.ts

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import {Component, View, bootstrap, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef } from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector:'my-app'
})
@View({
    template: '<h1>Hello {{name }}</h1>'
})
class MyAppComponent{
  name: string;

  constructor(loader: DynamicComponentLoader, elem: ElementRef) {
    this.name='World';
  }
}
bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

index.html

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 Demo</title>
    <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.91/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system.src.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true 
      });
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.39/angular2.dev.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <my-app></my-app>
    <script>System.import('app');</script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a known issue since alpha38 (see [#4497](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4497)), for now use `@Inject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you need to use `@Inject`. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4497 for details.

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import {Component, View, bootstrap, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef } from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector:'my-app'
})
@View({
    template: '<h1>Hello {{name }}</h1>'
})
class MyAppComponent{
  name: string;

  constructor(@Inject(DynamicComponentLoader) loader: DynamicComponentLoader, @Inject(ElementRef) elem: ElementRef) {
    this.name='World';
  }
}
bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is working perfectly fine. I tried to run it on my machine by just copying and pasting it. See the screenshot below and it injected the DynamicComponentLoader perfectly. I don't see any issues with code. The only difference i can think of is typescript compiler as i compiled with intelij idea with following parameters.
--experimentalDecorators --target es5 --experimentalDecorators --emitDecoratorMetadata true --module commonjs

[Screenshot shot of debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m56mK.png)